# Segue is executed twice

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, segue

I am trying to transition between view controllers with a segue. It is navigating correctly but it is running twice.

Here is my code:

```
- (IBAction)onActionNext:(id)sender {
    if ([[nameField.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]]isEqualToString:@""]) {

    }else if([[emailField.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]] isEqualToString:@""]){

    }else if([[mobileField.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]] isEqualToString:@""]){

    }else{
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"VerifyNext" sender:sender];
    }
}


- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"VerifyNext"]) {

        // Get destination view
        OTPSceneViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
        [vc setTitle:@"myapp"];
    }
}
```

Comment: ensure once are you added the Segueconnection in your button or VC

Comment: it seems you have segue with button to view controller, you should segue viewcontroller to view controller

Comment: I see only 2 reason for that. 1. May be you are tapping `actionNext` Button twice. Or you are calling `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"VerifyNext" sender:sender];` from two location. Check that and you will be good. Plus What Mike Alter said.

Comment: i am calling it only from tap of button. And segue is added from storyboard. if i comment the above code segue is still run. Does any thing need to be done in story board?

Comment: I have added an clean and elaborative answer based on Mark's suggestion and our previous conversation. Check that and let me know if problem still persist.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If even after commenting this line segue still run then as @mikealter said segue is connected your button. Check if when you check for when you click segue what it **highlights**.

A button like:

[image: When Segue is connected to a button]

Or A View Controller like:

[image: When Segue is connected to a viewController]

If you fall in first case that means your segue is connected to a button and, that is the reason why it opens next page even if you comment your code. And 2 times when you keep code(one from storyboard and another from code).

**Edit:**
If you want to call next page from code only. Remove Segue. Then reconnect it with view controller like:

[image]

Comment: i am falling in first case. So what should i do? Please help me

Comment: Happy to help. :-)

Answer (score 3):

First, whenever you create a segue (i.example) FROM a Button TO a View Controller, you are creating the link between VC1 and VC2.

If you run your project you will see that the segue works navigating from one VC to the other one.

This means that it already **performs** the segue, so if you declare an ACTION for your button and make a call to *- perform segue... -* it will run twice.

Note: if you call **performSegueWithIdentifier** is probably because you want to pass some data via SENDER. In that case you (obviously) need to call the segue ONCE, so instead of creating the segue from the button to the next VC, (first delete that segue), create a new one FROM the VCOrigin to VCDestination -> there are many ways to do it, but from the Interface Builder is as simple as *right click* on the top yellow rounded icon and drag&drop on the destinationVC. Don't forget to set the identifier on the Attributes Inspector.
Now, in your button~Action make the call to performSegueWithIdentifier and pass the data.

Answer (score 1):

if you stop storyboard segue use following method:

```
override func shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier(identifier: String,sender: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
        return false
    }
```

Comment: The question is about using objective-c not swift.

Answer (score 1):

You don't even add

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"VerifyNext" sender:sender];
```

in onActionNext method if you  add the segue in storyboard

If you want to navigate to next view controller use above line.

**Preparing for the Segue**

> In order to pass information from one view controller to another using
>   the UIStoryboardSegue object we’ll need to take advantage of the
>   current view controller’s prepareForSegue:sender: method.

But If you call both,it calls two times.So make sure that whether you want to pass information or data to next view controller or just navigate the view.

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{

   NSLog(@"prepareForSegue: %@", segue.identifier);
   if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"VerifyNext"])
   {
      VerifyNextViewController *verifyNVC = segue.destinationViewController;
      verifyNVC.name = @"Prashabt";
      verifyNVC.id = @"1234";
   }
   else if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"VerSeg"])
   {
      AnotherViewController *anotherVC = segue.destinationViewController;
      anotherVC.name = @"Sharma";
      anotherVC.id = @"3245";
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to use segue on certain condition. Please provide some sample code. It will be great help

Answer (score 0):

*have a look of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20231145/ios-segue-executed-twice) this may sure rectify*

or there is another way to navigate to another view controller using below code.

```
UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *vc = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"viewControllerName"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

> make sure you give identity to the view controller using identity inspector see image.

[image]